# Any fonts that'll allow me to see emojis?

Tags: fonts

I've searched this all over and all I get is webfonts. I don't want a webfont, I mean a font that I can install to my pc and see emojis instead of having to got to a site like iemoji.com to translate

I'm running Windows Vista so maybe that's why?

Comment: Emoji are some flavour of unicode, though fonts with 100% support prolly don't exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emoji characters not displaying correctly on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/183446/emoji-characters-not-displaying-correctly-on-windows-7)

Comment: @DavidPostill my question says right there. "Windows Vista"

Comment: @9Guy the techniques used for Windows 7 may work for Vista

Comment: @9Guy If you just want to see emojis while browsing the web, you can install [EmojiStuff Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emoji-input-by-emojistuff/immhpnclomdloikkpcefncmfgjbkojmh). It'll show iOS emojis whenever it sees unicode emojis online.

Comment: @Burgi nope, the link leads to a Windows 7 update package

Comment: You could probably do a quick Google for the font to download though. The accepted answer suggests "Segoe UI Symbol".

Comment: @Burgi good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to keep this vague so that I don't say something that's wrong.

At the lowest level, your computer doesn't know what letters are.  It only knows numbers.  Because of this, it pretends that certain numbers are certain letters, simple enough.  However, there's a lot of different ways to do this, and lots of people have tried making their own mappings.  ASCII and Unicode are two very popular ones, and you can look up exactly what number means what letter or character for those standards.  ASCII is an 8 bit system, meaning it can recognize up to 256 unique characters.  I believe Unicode can recognize up to 2147483647.

Essentially, your computer looks at characters using a numbering system that doesn't include emoji.  While it might seem easy to get one that does, the particular system that your computer uses doesn't even have enough slots to fit all the emoji you would want to use!

So, there's no way you can add emoji to windows at a system level.  You would have to use applications that would only recognize them within the scope of that application (which is what I presume webfont is?)

Comment: Actually, ASCII is a 7-bit code, allowing up to 128 characters, some of which are non-printable.

Comment: @RonMaupin ASCII is 8-bit.  Only the first 128 characters are standardized.

Comment: No, ASCII is 7-bit, and it always has been. Extensions, such as those by the ISO/IEC provide an 8-bit, character-compatible alternative to ASCII, but ASCII itself is, and always has been, a 7-bit code.

Comment: @RonMaupin Looks like I was misinformed.  ASCII is technically 7-bit.  But every notable use of it uses it as a 8-bit system, and an ASCII character is stored in 8 bits.

Comment: Old people, like me, remember these things. I remember telecommunications with ASCII. You could transfer faster if you used ASCII with only seven bits. Adding start and stop bits added a significant percentage to the slow transfers.

Comment: @RonMaupin That helps explain why the last 128 bits are so non-standard.  Very interesting.

Comment: so, the only solution is a new pc?

Comment: @9Guy No!  The solution is a new operating system.  However, I'm not aware of any desktop operating systems that support emoji.

Comment: @Nealon I know windows 7+ support emoji, and Windows 10 allows you to enter them in yourself.

Comment: And although one encoding (UCS-4) *could* go to 4294967295, *Unicode* is defined to never exceed the maximum set by UTF-16 which is 1114111 -- and currently includes 1624 emoji codepoints, see http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html (WARNING: BIG!) But the issue is having a font (or fonts) with a *glyph* at the (well-defined) codepoint. Webfont is a font downloaded from the web so you don't need it already installed on your system, and could among other things be a font that includes emoji glyphs.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 how does one install a webfont?

Comment: @9Guy On the client/browser you don't. On the server I expect it depends on the server but I haven't looked in any detail.

Comment: Accepted this answer 4 years later because to be honest at the time of you making this post, I had 0 idea what you and the commenters were talking about. Looking back you were totally correct